# simplify pseudo inverse of matrix with paired rows

Tags: inverse, svd, pseudoinverse

In remote sensing we often have a linear problem that can be written in a matrix form as $aAx+bAy=B$, where $a$ and $b$ are scalar constants, $A$ is a matrix; and  $x$, $y$, and $B$ are vectors (i.e. 1-column matrix). This can be further re-written as $\hat{A} \hat{x} = B$, where $\hat{A}$ is a matrix with 2 times more columns than $A$ (i.e. $\{aAbA\}$) and $\hat{x}$ is a vector with two times more rows than $x$ and $y$. Then we solve this problem by inverting the matrix $\hat{A}$ using the pseudoinverse (i.e. SVD): $\hat{x}=\hat{A}^{-1}B$.

The problem is that the computation of $\hat{A}^{-1}$ for each pixel is expensive. Knowing that the matrix $\hat{A}$ has a particular column structure, can the problem be reduced to inverting the matrix $A$ instead, which has half the amount of columns. In general, the matrix $A$ is rank deficient and overdetermined (i.e. more rows than columns, but rank is less or equal than the number of columns).

Answer (score 1):

I think that yes due to the following equation (this equation should be true for block-diagonal matrices)
\begin{equation}
\big(\begin{smallmatrix}
aA & 0\\
0 & bA
\end{smallmatrix}\big)\big(
\begin{smallmatrix}
a^{-1}A^{+} & 0\\
0 & b^{-1}A^{+}
\end{smallmatrix}\big) =
\big(\begin{smallmatrix}
aA a^{-1}A^{+} & 0\\
0 & bA b^{-1}A^{+}
\end{smallmatrix}\big) =
\big(\begin{smallmatrix}
I & 0\\
0 & I
\end{smallmatrix}\big),
\end{equation}
where $A^{+}$ is the pseudoinverse of $A$ and $I$ is the identity matrix. So, If I'm right, the pseudoinverse of $\hat{A}$ can be calculated using the following formula
\begin{equation}
\hat{A}^{+} = 
\big(\begin{smallmatrix}
a^{-1}A^{+} & 0\\
0 & b^{-1}A^{+}
\end{smallmatrix}\big).
\end{equation}